# How do you get a list of network interfaces in Mono on Mac?

Tags: c#, mono, monomac

Creating a Mono console application in MonoDevelop targeted at Mono/.NET 4.0 on OS X, to function as a TCP socket server.

The following line of code fails (that you would normally use on the Windows side of things):

```
var interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

... with error `System.DllNotFoundException: iphlpapi.dll`

Best I can tell this is only supported on Windows and Linux. However it seems there is another method designed for Mac:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.MacOsNetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

While that appears to be recognized by MonoDevelop, it fails to compile with a `The type or namespace 'MacOsNetworkInterface' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.NetworkInformation'.` error. Already have references to System and System.Net.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** Discovered that `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` does work when I create a new C# console app in MonoDevelop, but doesn't work within an existing project ([NetworkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/wiki/Home)) - they are both targeted the same, Mono, .NET 4.0 with same references to `System` and `System.Net` v4.0.0.0, what's the difference?

Comment: Probably an old Mono, works for me just fine.

Comment: I find this isn't working in Mono 3.0.6 on OSX, (Unexpected error: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateNLSocket). Anybody else having an issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call into low-level OS X APIs/Frameworks, [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) is your best candidate. However, not all OS X Frameworks are bound in MonoMac, yet. From the Apple Developer documentation, I take that you would need the functions from the [SystemConfiguration API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/_index.html) which isn't bound by MonoMac currently.

But you can always create a binding for the missing functions yourself using DllImport. I've recently done it with the DiskArbitration Framework (which isn't bound either) and you could use that as a reference: http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/tree/src/Backends/Banshee.Osx/Banshee.Hardware.Osx/LowLevel?id=136fcbcc2e0421aba6be79306dc111fdabb3c749